# extend lvm with existing partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm2

I have the following partitions:

```
    root@test02 [~]# df -l
    Filesystem           1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on 
    /dev/mapper/vg_test02-lv_root
                         119277820 4947592 108274344   5% /
    tmpfs                   961132       0    961132   0% /dev/shm
    /dev/sda1               495844   54380    415864  12% /boot
    /dev/sdb1            103211296  714176  97254292   1% /tmp

    root@test02 [~]# fdisk -l

    Disk /dev/sdb: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
    Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x000448a6

       Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sdb1               1       13055   104856576   83  Linux

    Disk /dev/sda: 128.8 GB, 128849018880 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15665 cylinders
    Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x0000c49e

       Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
    Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
    /dev/sda2              64       13055   104344576   8e  Linux LVM
    /dev/sda3           13055       15665    20971512+  8e  Linux LVM

    Disk /dev/mapper/vg_test02-lv_root: 124.1 GB, 124088483840 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15086 cylinders
    Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x00000000


    Disk /dev/mapper/vg_test02-lv_swap: 4227 MB, 4227858432 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 514 cylinders
    Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x00000000

    root@test02 [~]# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               vg_test02
  PV Size               99.51 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              25474
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          25474
  PV UUID               GS07qb-CYuk-ywp9-A3C5-HoRt-HF9L-tlkJmc

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda3
  VG Name               vg_test02
  PV Size               20.00 GiB / not usable 3.99 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              5119
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          5119
  PV UUID               dKk7VD-PZfO-9Zji-b8xq-WPP3-2tsG-sGJKFj

root@test02 [~]# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg_test02
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  9
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               119.50 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              30593
  Alloc PE / Size       30593 / 119.50 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               kPHRMG-yF75-j7pW-H3fR-cIvb-eQXD-inhdvI
```

**QUESTION:**
How can I extend my /dev/mapper/vg_test02-lv_root volume space using /dev/sdb1?

thank you very much

Comment: Please show the result of `pvdisplay` and `vgdisplay`

Comment: hi @shgnInc I have added the info requested. thanks!

Comment: You're currently using `/dev/sdb1`, as `/tmp`. Do you mean that you first want to take `/tmp` off of `/dev/sdb1` and put it somewhere else (say, your `/` partition)?

Answer (score 0):

For extending the LVM disk, change your sdb type to Linux LVM by `fdisk` and then creates a physical volume of that disk:

`pvcreate /dev/sdb1`

Then you have to extend the volume group which the logical disk is in and the check to extend correctly:

```
vgextend vg_group /dev/sdb1
vgdisplay
```

And for extending your logical disk:

```
lvextend /dev/vg_group/lv_disk /dev/sdb1
```

There is then one final step which is to resize the file system so that it can take advantage of this additional space, this is done using the resize2fs command.

```
resize2fs /dev/vg_group/lv_disk
```

Comment: where does `/dev/sda3` come from? shouldn't it be `lvextend /dev/vg_group/lv_disk /dev/sdb1`?